# Humans and Ages of Man

Tags: greek, creation, ages-of-man

I'm a little confused. In the Golden Age, it is said that humans and deities lived harmoniously, also living long lives. In the Silver Age, Zeus said that humans will live 100 years as children. But, because that did not pay tribute to the gods, Zeus killed them. The Bronze Age ends with the flood into the Heroic Age.

Here is what I'm confused about. If Prometheus created humans out of mud/clay/earth in the Bronze Age, how could humans have lived in the Gold and Silver Ages?

Comment: Assuming this is about Hesiod's ages of man, and not Ovids?  (They differ slightly, and Ovid came many centuries after Hesiod.)

Comment: Yes, it is as Ovid doesn't include the Heroic Age.

Comment: Why are you assuming the men of each age were created the same way? If I remember correctly, it's clear from Hesiod that this is not the case. The first two races were created by the Titans, the other three by Zeus.

Comment: I'm not assuming they were created that same way. I'm asking how they were in the other two ages. In other words, how where the humans in the Gold Age made?

Comment: Ok. This isn't clear from either the title or the question body. Please update them both to clarify exactly what you are asking about. Also, please tell us where you got the idea that Prometheus had a role in the Hesiodic tale of the Ages of Man. I don't think he did, and I think that is the source of the confusion.

Comment: Time isn't always linear in the canon, even within the work of a single author.  Close reading of the text in Greek may also provide some elucidation, but experience suggests this is merely a matter of paradoxes that commonly arise in mythological cycles.